# Linux - locate all children of a dying process (grandchildren of myself)

Tags: linux, daemon

Scenario: We have a linux daemon, call it Alpha. Alpha forks/execs a child process, Bravo. Bravo then spawns several child processes, call them Charlie and Delta.

```
Alpha
  |
   \-Bravo
     |
      \-Charlie
     |
      \-Delta
```

Bravo dies. Alpha has a sig child handler installed, which fires.

How do I, from Alpha, locate all the children of Bravo (Charlie and Delta) so that I can kill them as well?

What I have observed is that once Bravo is killed, Charlie and Delta become children of init (pid=1). I either need to be able to 1) examine the process tree BEFORE Bravo's children are reassigned, or 2) ensure somehow that Bravo's children are inherited by Alpha. If that were the case, I could sort out who was who among my (Alpha's) own children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use process groups for this.  When `Bravo` starts up, have it become a process group leader using `setpgid(0, 0);`, before it calls `execve()`.  Its children will then inherit this process group (which has a PGID equal to the PID of `Bravo`, and thus known to `Alpha`).

When `Bravo` exits, its children will be inherited by `init`, but their PGID will not change.  `Alpha` can then signal them all in one go using `kill()`, supplying the negative of the PGID as the first argument.  Eg. in `Alpha` you might do something like:

```
exited_child = wait(&status);
if (exited_child > 0)
     kill(-exited_child, SIGTERM);
```

Comment: Awesome. I have tested your suggestion. This is exactly what I needed.